# How to find the second derivative of a function using the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus

I have encountered this problem where I needed to use the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to find the second derivative of a function.

$\int_{0}^{x^3} e^{t^5}dt$

I found the first derivative of this function already and it seems to be

$(3x^2)*(e^{x^5})$

However, I couldn't seem to get the second derivative.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you so much!

Comment: The first derivative is not correct, it should be $3x^2 e^{x^{15}}$ (but I suppose that this is either a typo or an innocent mistake). To find the second derivative, use the product rule on the first derivative, and to differentiate $e^{x^{15}}$, use the chain rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g(x)=\frac{d{\int_{0}^{x^3} e^{t^5}dt}}{dx}=3x^2e^{x^{15}}$

$\frac{d  g(x)}{dx}=6x e^{x^{15}}+45x^{16}e^{x^{15}}= 3x(15x^{15}+2)e^{x^{15}}$